# Angular Language service in vscode: Strange behaviours

Tags: angular, angular-language-service

I have been using `webstorm` for a very long time, but now I am forced to use `VScode` regrettably.

Switching to `VScode` (and installing `Angular Language Service V14.1.0`), I observe even the basic features of language service arent working.

I am listing a few below:

I am getting this error: `"Class is using Angular features..."`. I dont see any problems with decorators.

[image]

Clicking on *app.component.html* doesnt take me to app.component.html file.

[image]

Clicking on a variable in HTML doesnt take me to variable declaeration
[image]

---

Angular CLI: 15.2.9
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.11
OS: darwin x64

Comment: The latest version of Angular Language Service is 16.1.8. Do the issues also occur with that version?

Comment: Yes updgraded to v16. same issue.

Comment: You can check the logs to see if there are any errors or warnings. Search for "Logs" using the command palette (Shift+Command+P).